# Aligning two tables in an EER diagram in MySQL Workbench's data modeling tool?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there any automatic way to align to tables in an EER diagram in MySQL Workbench's data modeling tool so as to make the relationship arrow straight?

E.g., before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I find it painful to do it manually each time.

I don't want to use the auto-layout feature as it often messes up, e.g. before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to have that straighten automatically. The grid snapping is done for the table figure, not the connection. The latter is always drawn centered (in most relationship notations). The only way to get this implemented is to file a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com.